# What is the significance of final instance variables?

Tags: java, static, constants, instance-variables, class-variables

I am having some confusion between `static final class variable` and `final instance variable`.

Here is the sample code:-

```
class Foof{
final int size=3;
final int whuffie;

    Foof()
    {
        whuffie=42; 
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Foof obj1 = new Foof();
        Foof obj2 = new Foof();

        obj1.size=53;    //compile time error
        System.out.println(obj1.size);
        obj2.whuffie=45; //compile time error
        System.out.println(obj2.whuffie);
    }
}
```

Error:-

```
ankit@stream:/home/Data/JAVA/practice/src/test.com/test-20121031_static_demystified$ javac Foof.java 
Foof.java:14: error: cannot assign a value to final variable size
obj1.size=53;    //compile time error
    ^
Foof.java:16: error: cannot assign a value to final variable whuffie
obj2.whuffie=45;
    ^
2 errors
```

So my question is, what is the point of having final instance variables if they can't have a different values per different instance. I mean if they have same value for each instance then why don't we declare them as class variable(static final class variable) as this would serve the same purpose and the we don't need to create objects in order to access them.

---

EDIT -1:-

```
class Foof{
    final int size=3;
    final int whuffie;

    Foof()
    {
        whuffie=42;
        size = 23;  //compile-time error.
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Foof obj1 = new Foof();
        Foof obj2 = new Foof();

        //obj1.size=53;    
        System.out.println(obj1.size);
        //obj2.whuffie=45; 
        System.out.println(obj2.whuffie);
    }
}
```

Error:-

```
Foof.java:8: cannot assign a value to final variable size
size = 23;
^
1 error
```

According to the error, i can make out that first size is assigned a value =3 during object creation.

Comment: Your comments claim three compile-time errors. There are only two.

Comment: @Jon, i was assuming that the constructor-code would also generate an error; but it didn't.

Comment: `what is the point of having final instance variables if they can't have a different values per different instance` They can. You can set it in the constructor of said object, either by obtaining it from some logic, or receiving it as a parameter... This is exactly the same Jon Skeet referred: the constructor setting will not give a compile error.

Comment: @Ankit: Why would you not test the assumption *before* posting the question? Always do research before you ask questions, not afterwards...

Comment: @Jon, i will take care in future. Edited my question to show only 2 compile time errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So my question is, what is the point of having final instance variables if they can't have a different values per different instance.

They can, but those values can't be changed *after creation*. You can only assign values to final instance fields within instance variable initializers and constructors, and you *must* assign values to all instance fields that way.

Note that in your code here:

```
Foof()
{
    whuffie=42;  //compile time error
}
```

... the comment is incorrect. That assignment should be perfectly valid.

Final fields are useful for implementing *immutability* - which helps make it easy to reason about an object. For example, `String` is immutable, so if you validate a string and then keep a copy of the reference, you know that validation will still be correct later on.

Compare that with `java.util.Date`, where if you *really* want to have any faith in validation being useful, you need to create a defensive copy of the `Date` value and not provide the reference to any other code, in case it changes the underlying instant being represented.

Comment: i tried to change the value of the size (currently 3) to 23 in the constructor but still getting the error.

Comment: @Ankit: Then you need to remove the initializer expression. Basically, you can only set a final variable *once*.

Answer (score 2):

A `final` is final as soon as you asign a value to it. You can't change it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a `final` variable after initializing on declaration or in the constructor(s).

Using the `static` keyword doesn't make it **modifiable**. It just means the `final` variable can be accessed through the class name or instance variable, the variable is still **immutable**.

Comment: got the point; but wouldn't it be good to make the variable static because my code wouldn't have to deal with object creation(saving memory.)

Comment: Ha ha, not a good reason really :) If you want more memory then buy it, not as expensive as before :P And it could be a pain to maintain later. So unless it makes sense to expose your code then it is fine. Making it a final variable makes it slightly OK.

Answer (score 1):

Actually static and non static final variable are needs when we are creating any varible as a class specific then will declare it as static and if object level then will declare it as non static variable.

For example,
We have a country as a class and  and will have two data members of that class like
timezone and gravity.
we declred both of them as final, but timezone is object specific(timezone of every country is different but same throughout the country) and gravity is class specific(gravity of each country is same as earths gravity) so we are declared gravity as static final.

Answer (score 0):

`final` variables are typically used to define things that should never change. You can write to it *one time* and then it is set forever.

You might use this in a constructor to set an ID for an object or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For final variables you can assign value only once.
It is generally used in case where you don't want the values of variables to be changed later in your program.

Static variables only one instance is created per class, irrespective of number of objects of that class you create.